# Keyboard is hiding TextFormField only in case of selecting all text by tapping on it or else on long press Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on a requirement where **on a single tap I need to select all the text from TextFormField** and letting user to delete it and setting a new value to it, the reason is to not allow the user to manipulate the old value in TextFormField.

But the issue I am facing in it is like **keyboard is showing above the TextFormField when I tried to tap the text**, the strange thing is, in general it is working fine, only in case of all text selection Keyboard is hiding the TextFormField.

**Below I have uploaded two gif, first one is for single tap text selection behaviour and second one is generic behaviour without single tap selection.**

[image: While Selecting all text on Tap]

[image: While not selecting all text on Tap, Generic case]

Adding the code below, below code is a skeleton of original code.

```
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  final _textFieldKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _textController.text = "DemoText";
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 100,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _scrollController,
                child: Column(children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    height: 400,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          key: _textFieldKey,
                          controller: _textController,
                          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                          keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                          onTap: () {
                            final textLength = _textController.value.text.length;
                            _textController.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: textLength);
                          }, // responsible for selecting text on single tap or click
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(8),
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(8),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, tried lot of things but it needs just one thing in SingleChildScrollView.

```
reverse: true
```

Thats it it solves the problem.